# Getting an exact copy of my Miktex installation on a new machine

Tags: miktex

I have the latest version of Miktex 2.9 installed on a Windows 10 machine. Through the years I have added fonts and packages to this installation (including some proprietary fonts) and the system works fine. Now I have a new machine and would like to have an exact copy of this installation on the new machine. I know that I have to install Miktex on the new machine and then copy some of my folders from the old machine to the new one but I am not sure about the right order of operation and which folders to copy.

I have noted "Program Files\Miktex2.9" and "\users...\AppData\local\Miktex\2.9" and "\users...\AppData\Roaming\Miktex\2.9" and "ProgramData\Miktex\2.9" folders to be relevant. Do I need to copy all these folders to the new machine after installation of Miktex? Or maybe first copying some of these folders and then installing Miktex?

Comment: Depends where your local files are. I normally put them in dedicated own roots so that I know what to backup.

Comment: I would reinstall everything including all the packages.  The contents wind up spread all over the place.  Only things like non-MikTeX fonts need to be copied.

Comment: @John Kormylo The problem is that some of these files (like Lucida Bright fonts and related files) were installed a long time ago and I do not have the documentation to re-install them and I even do not know the location of these fonts on my system. These are the fonts that I call by using lucimatx.sty and I could not find any documentation on the internet for installing them.

Comment: Technically they could be anywhere.  I would check `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts` first.

Comment: MikTeX console Settings->Directories should list any added locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to install a new, complete miktex system. Update it and then copy over the old roots but tell windows not to overwrite existing files (the AppData\local\Miktex\2.9 is probably not needed, it normally only contains files that can be easily recreated when needed).

Then run in the console the tasks "refresh file name database" and "refresh font map files".

But I would instead invest some time and use some diff program  to find the local files and move them to a dedicated root. This will make backups and later moves to other systems easier. If you do this don't forget to check the updmap.cfg(s) for personal map entries. Copy them to a new updmap.cfg in your new root in miktex/config.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "and then copy over the old roots but tell windows not to overwrite existing files" you mean copy both "Program File\Miktex 2.9" and "\users...\AppData\Roaming\Miktex\2.9"? Or you mean  "ProgramData\Miktex\2.9" and "\users...\AppData\Roaming\Miktex\2.9" as well?

Comment: @per you will have to decide it yourself. Look in the roots and make educated guess if they contain files that you need in the new installation.

Comment: one more question: I cannot find the complete installation on MikTeX site anymore. It only has the basic installation. Do you know where the complete installation is located?

Comment: I got the answer to my question! it is the net installer that installs all packages.